# Probability of drawing 3 balls

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

A box contains 8 red, 3 white, and 9 blue balls. If 3 balls are drawn at random determine the probability that

- all 3 balls are red
- all 3 balls are white
- 2 are red and 1 is white
- at least 1 is white

What I tried for the first one is

3/20 * 2/19 * 1/18  = 6/6840

But they said it was wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are $8$ balls that are red. So you should have $$(1)\quad \dfrac {8}{20}\cdot \frac 7{19}\cdot \frac 6{18} = \frac{336}{6840} = \frac{14}{285}$$

What you actually calculated is the probability that all three balls are *white*: $$(2)\quad \dfrac 3{20}\cdot \dfrac 2{19}\cdot \frac 1{18} = \dfrac{6}{6840} = \dfrac 1{1140}$$

For $(3)$, there are three ways to get draw 2 red balls and 1 white ball: RRW, RWR, WRR. Add the probabilities of each of the three sequences of draws to find the overall probability of drawing $2$ red balls and one white ball.

For $(4)$, compute the probability of getting zero white balls, and subtract it from $1$ to obtain the probability of getting at least one white ball.

Comment: Could use another TU, so +1

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Taking $3$ balls from $20$ gives $\left({20\atop 3}\right)$
possibilities. Taken $3$ balls from $8$ (the red ones) gives $\left({8\atop 3}\right)$
possibilities.